# Function not fully cycling through for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, for-loop, indexof

I have formatted the second script so it could be easily read in notepad ++ which is the problematic one, the first is just so you have arrays to work with...Anyways I created this script to replace words with pre-existing numbers in the forms, it works fine cycling through the first key which is "movespeed/movrate" but after when it gets down to str and strrate, it literally cuts off where I have commented `//Doesn't get past here?`
It get's initialized through an onClick (it's a button)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var key = new Array();
var val = new Array();
key.push("movespeed");
val.push("1");
key.push("str");
val.push("4");
key.push("dex");
val.push("3");
key.push("int");
val.push("1");
key.push("will");
val.push("2");
key.push("Movrate");
val.push("Mov+1");
key.push("strrate");
val.push("1+str");
key.push("dexrate");
val.push("1+dex+(str/4)");
key.push("intrate");
val.push("1+int");
key.push("willrate");
val.push("1+will");
</script>
```

Apologies if the above script is messing, it was generated by the page..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function Update() {
    for (i = 0; i <= key.length; i++) {
        if (key[i].indexOf("rate") > -1) { //Search through
            for (r = 0; r <= key.length; r++) {
                alert("Checked:" + key[r] + " In:" + key[i]);
                if (key[i].indexOf(key[r]) > -1) { //Finds out which form it should replace
                    alert("Passed:" + key[r] + " In:" + key[i]);
                    var raw = val[i];
                    for (y = 0; y <= key.length; y++) {
                        if (key[i] != "movespeed" && key[i] != "Movrate") { //add a check to see if string is not there
                            //alert("string:"+raw);
                            //raw=raw.replace(key[y],Number(document.getElementById(key[y]).value));
                            raw = raw.replace(key[y], document.getElementById(key[y]).value);
                            //alert("Changed:"+key[y]);
                            alert(raw);
                        } else break;
                        alert("hi");
                    } //Doesn't get past here?
                    alert("key[i]:" + key[i] + "Key[r]:" + key[r]);
                    if (raw.indexOf("Mov") > -1) {
                        for (x = 0; x <= key.length; x++) {
                            if (key[x].indexOf("movespeed") > -1) {
                                raw = raw.replace("Mov", document.getElementById(key[x]).value);
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (raw.indexOf("Lvl") > -1) {
                        raw = raw.replace("Lvl", document.getElementById('Lvl').value);
                    }
                    if (raw.indexOf("Exp") > -1) {
                        raw = raw.replace("Exp", "0");
                        //Change this to exp...you also need to add an exp to the formula system, derpy.
                    }
                    alert(raw);
                    if (key[i] == "Movrate") {
                        document.getElementById("movespeed").value = eval(raw);
                    } else {
                        document.getElementById(key[i]).value = eval(raw);
                    }
                    break; //So it doesn't keep searching
                }
            }
        }
        alert(key[i]);
    }
}
</script>
```

Html(It was generated through the php but it should work fine without having to be generated)

```
   Files<br>======================<br>Basic.xml<br>======================<br><table><tbody><tr><td>Creature Name:</td><td><input type="Text" name="CName" value="Thing" size="10%"></td></tr><tr><td>Level:</td><td><input type="Text" id="Lvl" name="level" onchange="alert('hi')" value="1" size="10%"></td></tr><tr><td>movespeed:</td><td><input type="Text" name="movespeed" id="movespeed" value="1" size="10%"></td></tr><tr><td>str:</td><td><input type="Text" name="str" id="str" value="4" size="10%"></td></tr><tr><td>dex:</td><td><input type="Text" name="dex" id="dex" value="3" size="10%"></td></tr><tr><td>int:</td><td><input type="Text" name="int" id="int" value="1" size="10%"></td></tr><tr><td>will:</td><td><input type="Text" name="will" id="will" value="2" size="10%"></td></tr><script type="text/javascript">var key=new Array();var val=new Array();key.push("movespeed");val.push("1");key.push("str");val.push("4");key.push("dex");val.push("3");key.push("int");val.push("1");key.push("will");val.push("2");key.push("Movrate");val.push("Mov+1");key.push("strrate");val.push("1+str");key.push("dexrate");val.push("1+dex+(str/4)");key.push("intrate");val.push("1+int");key.push("willrate");val.push("1+will");</script><tr><td><input type="button" name="button" value="Update" onclick="Update();"></td><td><input type="submit" value="Save"></td><script type="text/javascript">
```

Comment: For one, you should declare all your `for` loop index variables as local variables so they aren't implicitly global.  Secondly, have you checked the error console to see if any script errors are reported?  Thirdly, `console.log()` is probably way easier in this case than a zillion `alert()` boxes popping up.

Comment: Have you checked your console for errors?

Comment: Is there a reason you opted for 2 Arrays instead of an Object?  `{'movespeed': 1, 'str': 4, ... }`?

Comment: I would've done a two dimensional array but I was trying not to over complicate things

Comment: Added html so it could be read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

logic problem, I used i instead of r, changing it to r fixed it completely. Human mistake, thanks everyone though you guys provided some useful tips I wasn't aware of:

```
var check = document.getElementById(key[r]);
                    if (check){
                        document.getElementById(key[r]).value = eval(raw);
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't given us any code we can actually run/debug, all we can do is offer possibilities that you will have to investigate and debugging techniques to help you solve it yourself:

1. Check the error console or debug console for script errors.  If your script is stopping prematurely, then the console is probably reporting an error.
2. Declare all your loop variables as local variables so they aren't implicit globals.
3. Change your `alert()` calls to `console.log()` so you can more easily track the sequence of events.
4. Step through your code in the debugger and see exactly what is failing by watching it execute line by line and examining the variables as it goes.
5. This line could cause an error if the HTML didn't contain an id you were expecting.

   `raw=raw.replace(key[y],document.getElementById(key[y]).value);`

You could make that code safer like this:

```
var item = document.getElementById(key[y]);
if (item) {
    raw=raw.replace(key[y],document.getElementById(key[y]).value);
}
```

Comment: Mind me but how would I go about using a debugger?

Comment: It varies by browser.  But go to Google and search for "How to set breakpoint in xxx" where xxx is the name of your browser.  For example, in Chrome it's this: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/scripts-breakpoints.

Comment: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null " appears on the line I suspected to be faulty

Comment: okay using your method I repaired the uncaught type errors, but the script still isn't working past the movespeed